# How to check a Jenkins slave connection status from the slave itself?

Tags: jenkins

I am building a system that monitors whether a Jenkins slave is connected or not using only data collected from the slave itself, meaning no API call from master.

What I want to ask is if this is possible or not and if possible, how should I approach it. Jenkins is mostly installed as a service on these machines but there are instances where it is run ad-hoc. I figure if I can check for node availability from master, there must be a way they are communicating so I tried checking for packets sending to master but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

I've researched a little bit and checked what was going on when the Agent was on and when the Agent was off.

Basically, when the agent is connected, there's a port for the connection between the Agent and the Master. When I click `ctrl+c` to stop the Agent then it closes right away.

So the easiest solution you can to check whether the Agent is connected or not is by using

`netstat | findstr MasterComputerName`

So if my master computer name is "SHLOMI-BAZEL" it would be
`netstat | findstr SHLOMI-BAZEL`

If it returns an empty line, then it means the Agent has no active connection to the master, else - the connection is active.